# Restoring my Backup

Tags: backup, windows-7, backup-restoration

Is it possible to copy all the data in the C drive of a machine to the C drive of another machine (which has totally different hardware) and then boot the new machine with it?

Comment: If the other machines is similar in hardware then it sometimes works. If not search for imaging tools, windows AIK, WIM images, sysprep etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've done that maybe 7-8 times on different computers.
In all of my experience trying to do this, I ended up with a blue screen crash.
Some computers were totally different, some were pretty similar (Dell Latitude D630 and D630c)..